# Celery Abstract Task event handlers not executed

Tags: python, celery

I have a single abstract Task class set for 3 different tasks. For one task, the after_return/on_success event handlers are executing fine, but for the other two tasks - the event handlers are not executed despite celeryd showing "task completed successfully". What could be the issue here?

Comment: Can you share the code?